# Define r.v. by partition of $\Omega$ and other integrable r.v., and show its integrable

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ be a probability space, and let $\{ A_i \}_{i\in I}$ be an at most countable partition of $\Omega$ (i.e. $I = \{1,\ldots, n\}$ or $I = \mathbb N$). Also let $X : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ be a random variable, define the random variable (suppose $P(A_i) > 0$)
$$
 Y := \sum_{i \in I} \frac{E[X \cdot I_{A_i}]}{P(A_i)} \cdot I_{A_i} 
$$
which is a function constant on each $A_i$ (indeed it is the conditional expectation $E[X | \sigma(\{ A_i \} : i \in I)]$, but this doesn't matter with respect to my question). Then if $X$ is integrable (i.e. $E[|X|] < \infty$), is then $Y$ integrable too, i.e. does $E[Y]$ exists?

If $I = \{1,\ldots, n\}$ we would have
$$
 E[|Y|] \le \int_{\Omega} \sum_{i=1}^n \left| \frac{E[X\cdot I_{A_i}]}{P(A_i)} \cdot I_{A_i} \right| dP
 = \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{\Omega} \left| \frac{E[X\cdot I_{A_i}]}{P(A_i)} \right|I_{A_i} dP = \sum_{i=1}^n \left| \frac{E[X\cdot I_{A_i}]}{P(A_i)} \right| P(A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n |E[X\cdot I_{A_i}]| \le \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{A_i} |X| dP
= E[|X|] < \infty
$$
but for $I = \mathbb N$ I am not sure if all these rearrangement are valid, they would if we could apply the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem), but this would require for each $n$
$$
 \left| \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{E[X \cdot I_{A_i}]}{P(A_i)} \cdot I_{A_i}(\omega) \right| \le g(\omega)
$$
for some integrable, i.e. $\int_{\Omega} |g| ~ dP < \infty$, function $g : \Omega \to \mathbb R$. But everything I can get here is that if $\omega \in A_j$ (which must be the case for some $A_j$ as this is a partition), then
$$
 \left| \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{E[X \cdot I_{A_i}]}{P(A_i)} \cdot I_{A_i}(\omega) \right|
 \le \left| \frac{E[X \cdot I_{A_j}]}{P(A_j)} \right| \le \frac{E[|X|]}{P(A_j)}
$$
which does not make it easier, as for example showing that $g(\omega) := \sum_{i\in I} \frac{E[|X|]}{P(A_i)} I_{A_i}(\omega)$ is integrable does not seem simpler (without being able to get the sum out of the integral).

Comment: In the second line there should be inequality when you move from $|\mathbb{E}[\cdot]|$ to $\mathbb{E}|\cdot|$...

Comment: You can interchange summation and integral when the integrand is non-negative (Fubini).

Comment: So, $E|Y|=\int \left|\sum_{i\in I} \frac{E[X\cdot I_{A_i}]}{P(A_i)} \cdot I_{A_i} \right| dP \le \int \sum_{i\in I} \left| \frac{E[X\cdot I_{A_i}]}{P(A_i)} \cdot I_{A_i} \right| dP
 = \sum_{i\in I} \int \frac{|E[X\cdot I_{A_i}]|}{P(A_i)} I_{A_i} dP$

Comment: Yes, I fixed that. Okay, strictly you mean Tonelli's Theorem,which is the one for non-negative $f$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem. But yes, when equipping $\mathbb N$ with the counting measure and integrating with respect to $\mathbb N \times \Omega$ it yields the interchangibility of a sum and an integral.